# phpmyadmin: Connection failed: Unknown database.

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, connection

I'm a beginner and a teacher trying to make a quiz and connect to the database. I'm using MAMP 7.0.6, also installed XAMPP on my window. I had a database called "students" on phpmyadmin and a script like this:

```
  <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "students";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

It works fine when I tried to connect to the database without the $dbname, however, when I included that it says "Connection failed: Unknown database 'students'". I'm sure the name and username, password and stuff is correct, even though I don't know why the password has to be "" instead of the one shown on my phpmyadmin, but it works so I'll just leave it for later unless some of you would like to spend the time to explain it to me. 
I just want to make this work asap coz it has been bugging me for a few days and I still can't find the solution online. I need to get the quiz done by mid August so thank you so much in advance!!!!

Comment: no. you don't have a "database on phpmyadmin". phpmyadmin is a MANAGEMENT interface for the mysql database server.

Comment: so what do I have to do to create a database so I can store and edit all my quiz question on a database and I don't have to put the questions in my script? And what's is that "database" for on myphpadmin? thanks.

Comment: Your terminology is a bit off, but you should confirm that you can connect to the MySQL server through localhost. I recommend running a copy of MySQLWorkbench to confirm your setup is correct and that permissions on students is correct.